# Rendering JSON arrays of unequal length as a table

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, iterator, vue.js

I have a website where my users can create "table-like" layout dynamically. So imagine that my users can upload a text document, and then append columns to the document, and the output will then be parsed into a table-like layout.

For example:

```
My text document              Date: 20-06-2019                Created by: OJN

Content                       Nice Document                   Very!

Content                       Indeed!

                              Even more!
```

Now imagine that this is a word document for example, and my users have defined two columns on above (right between each block of text). This would output:

```
{
   "1":[
      {
         "row":"My text document"
      },
      {
         "row":"Content"
      },
      {
         "row":"Content"
      }
   ],
   "2":[
      {
         "row":"Date: 20-06-2019"
      },
      {
         "row":"Nice Document"
      },
      {
         "row": "Indeed!"
      },
      {
         "row": "Even more!"
      }
   ],
   "3":[
      {
         "row":"Created by: OJN"
      },
      {
         "row":"Very!"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, this will ultimately generate three array objects with unequal elements.

```
0: Array(3)
1: Array(4)
2: Array(2)
```

Now when presenting this for the user in the frontend, I wish to show the parsed text content in a table, like: this

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in dataTable" :key="index">
      <td v-for="(cell, index) in row" :key="index">
        <span v-if="cell">{{cell["row"]}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, as said, the arrays are of unequal length - so if I "just" transpose them, it will not generate the desired output. Instead, in above example, it will only create **3** rows in my table, because the first array contains 3 elements.

So in order to overcome this, I check the arrays to find the largest one:

```
// Transform object in array of its values
let data = Object.values(content);
let colsLength = data.map(r => r.length);
let maxNumCols = Math.max.apply(Math, colsLength);
let recordArraySchema = Array.apply(null, Array(maxNumCols)).map((r, i) => i);

this.dataTable = recordArraySchema.map((col, i) => data.map(row => row[i]));
```

This way, the array transposing will transpose all "rows", and fill the "empty"/non-existing will null, resulting in a full table.

I was wondering if this approach is acceptable in terms of performance and readability? I do have the option to change the JSON string format all together on the backend if that is more appropriate. However, I do have other backend functions that relies on the current schema, so those would have to be updated as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that the format of the data is a collection of columns with rows. The variable `maxNumCols` seems mis-leading. A more appropriate name for that variable would be `maxNumRows` because it describes how many rows are needed.

In terms of reducing the transformations needed, one option to consider is finding the maximum number of rows in a column and using that with [`v-for` _with a Range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) to determine how many rows to add. Then looping over the `content` would eliminate the need to create `recordArraySchema` and `dataTable` - which would reduce the complexity from \$O(n^2)\$ to just \$O(n)\$.

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="r in maxNumRows">
      <td v-for="(column, index) in content" :key="index">
        <span v-if="column[r - 1]">{{column[r - 1].row}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously this would require saving `maxNumRows` in the `data` collection.

Instead of using `Function.apply()` the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to determine the maximum number of rows.

```
const rowLengths = data.map(r => r.length);
this.maxNumRows = Math.max(...rowLengths);
```

And instead of using `let` for variables that are only assigned once, it is wise to use `const` and then if it is determined that it needs to be re-assigned, use `let`. This helps avoid accidental re-assignment.